# Apache Solr query for date time range for field having string value

Tags: database, solr

One of field name "lastModifiedTimeStamp" is in string format. sample value of the fields are like below.

"06/16/2021 8:11:17.525"

I would like to use date range for the field "lastModifiedTimeStamp" where user specifies long number for given date

for example: lastModifiedTimeStamp: [223232323 TO 2323233232]

Comment: Have you already indexed the field in this format, or are you asking how you can convert it as you ingest the documents? Where does the data come from? (SQL-database? which type is the column?)

Comment: type of the column is String.

Comment: i need a range for lastModifiedTimeStamp like below.

Comment: You're not going to solve this with a string field type (the sort order will _not_ match what you need for the query you want to solve). Reindex the content as a field type that matches how you want to query it - i.e. index it converted to an integer value.